# Regex for excluding words at start of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regex to exclude the first part of string as highlighted (the words WASH HANDLING PLANT are to be excluded).

**`WASH HANDLING PLANT`** `PRODUCT CONVEYOR TAIL END GUARDING`

When the regex is run, the result is:

HANDLING PLANT PRODUCT CONVEYOR TAIL END GUARDING.

Can anyone please advise how I can get the regex to work?

Thank you.

```
var re = new RegExp(/\b(?!WASH\sHANDLING\s[A-z ]{1,3})\b[-A-z0-9 ]{2,90}/);
```

Comment: Does the string have fixed format? Try `if (s.slice(0,19) === "WASH HANDLING PLANT") {
  console.log(s.slice(20));
}`. Or can `PLANT` be any word and `WASH HANDLING` are "hardcoded"?Then try `/^WASH\s+HANDLING\s+\w+\s*([\s\S]*)/.exec(s)[1]`.

Comment: Could you please clarify the requirements? What exactly the first part may comprise? If it's any three words, `input.replace(/^(\w+\s+){3}/, "")` would do the job. If it's exactly `"WASH HANDLING PLANT"`, then the regex even more straightforward.

Comment: Careful, `[A-z]` does *not* match what you think. Use `[A-Za-z]` or `[A-Z]` with the `/i` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's literally the words "WASH HANDLING PLANT" that need removing then this RegEx will provide a match

```
/^(WASH HANDLING PLANT)/
```

To remove the words use a string replace function like the following Javascript example...

```
mystring.replace(/^(WASH HANDLING PLANT)/, "");
```

If its more elaborate and you need to remove the first three words regardless then this should work for you...

```
/^(\w+\s){3}/
```

and again with Javascript replace...

```
mystring.replace(/^(\w+\s){3}/, "");
```

To explain whats going on in the second one...

`^` Matches the start of the string. The `()`'s signify the group of words or characters to match (We are only matching one group here), `\w`matches any word, and `\s`matches whitespace. We repeat this three times with `{3}`

Comment: The first replace would strip `WASH HANDLING PLANT` from the end of `PRODUCT CONVEYOR TAIL END GUARDING WASH HANDLING PLANT`, which breaks the "exclude the first part of string" requirement.